# How to create persistent docker volume with size limitation?

Tags: size, volume, persistent

Docker volume docs do not provide info about this.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.